# How do I un-expose (undo expose) service?

Tags: service, kubernetes

In Kubernetes, it is possible to make a service running in cluster externally accessible by running `kubectl expose deployment`.  Why deployment as opposed to service is beyond my simpleton's comprehension.  That aside, I would like to also be able to undo this operation afterwards.  Think of a scenario, where I need to get access to the service that normally is only accessible inside the cluster for debugging purposes and then to restore original situation.

Is there any way of doing this short of deleting the deployment and creating it afresh?

---

PS. Actually deleting service and deployment doesn't help. Re-creating service and deployment with the same name will result in service being exposed.

Comment: from where do you need access ? from pods, from the vpc ? from external?   expose just creates a service that maps your deployment labels, you can just delete the service if you want and keep the deployment, you can even have more than one service that maps the same pods. one for internal and one for you external tests and when you are done you can remove the external.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Assuming you have a deployment called hello-world, and do a kubectl expose as follows:

`kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=ClusterIP --name=my-service`

this will create a service called my-service, which makes your deployment accessible for debugging, as you described.

To display information about the Service:

`kubectl get services my-service`

To delete this service when you are done debugging:

`kubectl delete service my-service`

Now your deployment is un-exposed.

Comment: It may be worth driving attention to the fact that the service created for this purpose is a separate entity. In a typical scenario, one would want to expose an existing service and would expect that service's configuration to be affected by the operation. It's entirely not obvious that a new service is created for this. BTW. Is there any way to create a service which is already exposed? As in, exposed to the internet outside the cluster?

Comment: You can also write services separately from deployments. If you want to expose your deployment to the internet, create a service of type LoadBalancer. This will create a service with an external IP. To then access your program, `curl http://<external-ip>:<port>`.
This doc might help you out: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

Comment: I deleted the service, put the pod remained accesible until i deleted the pod too